# Best decision I/I've ever made-- difference?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

> I started watching that show a few months ago. Best decision **I've** ever made.
>
> I started watching that show a few months ago. Best decision **I** ever made.

What's the difference between the two sentences meaning wise?
Is the **I've** and **I** just a difference between American English, and British English, I read it somewhere that Americans oftentimes don't use *have* in such cases as the one used in the sentences above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the information a listener would extract I don't think that there is much, if any, practical difference between the two.

Grammatically, the first example uses the present perfect tense, in which making the decision [to watch the show] occurred at an unspecified point in the past and may still have relevance in the present. The second example uses the past indicative tense but does not specify a point in time any more than the first example and does not suggest direct relevance to the present.

I personally would prefer the first example in cases where I am *still watching* the show or otherwise currently engaging with it in some way, and the second in a case where I've watched every episode and no longer engage with the show in any way. However, if I were trying to express those ideas I would not rely on verb tense alone like this to convey my meaning.

Comment: I think your opening statement is even more true in a case like this one, where "best decision ever" is really more hyperbole than an accurate rank ordering of life decisions.